# Query to get posts and if the user has voted for the post

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having a hard time describing this and it's very possible that I am making this more difficult than it should be...

Basically, I have a page filled with pins/posts and users can upvote or downvote them. In one query, I want to get a list of the pins, but also join two tables to see if the user has upvoted or downvoted them.

The table structures:

```
pins table

|  id  |       title       |
+------+-------------------+
    1         Post 1
    2         Post 2
    3         Post 3
    4         Post 4

user_upvotes table

|  id  |  user_id  |  pin_id  |
+------+-----------+----------+
   1         1           2
   2         2           1
   3         2           3
   4         2           1

user_downvotes table

|  id  |  user_id  |  pin_id  |
+------+-----------+----------+
   1         2           2
   2         1           1
   3         1           3
   4         1           1
```

Here's the query I have tried, but ends up duplicating the pins on the page.

```
SELECT pins.id AS pin_id, title, user_upvotes.id AS upvote, user_downvotes.id AS downvote
FROM pins
LEFT JOIN user_upvotes ON user_upvotes.pin_id = pins.id AND user_upvotes.user_id = 2
LEFT JOIN user_downvotes ON user_downvotes.pin_id = pins.id AND user_downvotes.user_id = 2
```

This results in (notice that pin_id 1 is repeated twice):

```
| pin_id |       title       |  upvote  |  downvote  |
|   1    |       Post 1      |  (NULL)  |      2     |
|   1    |       Post 1      |  (NULL)  |      4     |
|   2    |       Post 2      |     1    |    (NULL)  |
|   3    |       Post 3      |  (NULL)  |      3     |
|   4    |       Post 4      |  (NULL)  |    (NULL)  |
```

From this point I just check if the value is NULL and if not, I attach a css class to indicate that it has been upvoted or downvoted.

Essentially, I want the above results, just without the pin being duplicated. If you have a better way of doing this, feel free to let me know that as well.

Comment: You should just keep on field and defalut set it to 0 increse or decrese counter accordinly for upvotes and downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add GROUP BY

```
SELECT pins.id AS pin_id, title, user_upvotes.id AS upvote, user_downvotes.id AS downvote
FROM pins
LEFT JOIN user_upvotes ON user_upvotes.pin_id = pins.id AND user_upvotes.user_id = 2
LEFT JOIN user_downvotes ON user_downvotes.pin_id = pins.id AND user_downvotes.user_id = 2
GROUP BY pin_id
```

Answer (score 1):

That would probably mean that the user has upvoted or downvoted the same pin twice. Since you include the id of the vote in the results, you get the distinct votes as separate records.

I think you either want a count, or you want to prevent double votes at all. 
Count is done as follows:

```
SELECT 
  pins.id AS pin_id, 
  title, 
  COUNT(user_upvotes.id) AS upvotes, 
  COUNT(user_downvotes.id) AS downvotes
FROM pins
LEFT JOIN user_upvotes ON user_upvotes.pin_id = pins.id AND user_upvotes.user_id = 2
LEFT JOIN user_downvotes ON user_downvotes.pin_id = pins.id AND user_downvotes.user_id = 2
GROUP BY 
  pins.id
```

Now you can display the count, or just show it as Yes or No depending on whether it's > 0 or not.

Comment: Yours is the only answer that recognizes that the upvote and downvote totals come from arbitrary records and may not contain non-NULL data.  The `count` fixes this problem.

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't this help?

```
 SELECT pins.id AS pin_id, title, user_upvotes.id AS upvote, user_downvotes.id AS downvote
 FROM pins
 LEFT JOIN user_upvotes ON user_upvotes.pin_id = pins.id AND user_upvotes.user_id = 2
 LEFT JOIN user_downvotes ON user_downvotes.pin_id = pins.id AND user_downvotes.user_id = 2
 **GROUP BY pins.id**
```